# Google Cloud Function undefined argument detected as null

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

When I pass an undefined argument to my cloud function, it is detected as null. For example, if I have this:

```
 const a = undefined;

 firebase.functions().httpsCallable("myFunction")({
    a
 });
```

And in my cloud function I do:

```
...
.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

    const {a} = data;

    console.log(a);

    ...
});
```

It prints "null" and not "undefined".

> myFunction: null

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call your remote function, the payload (ie. your `data`) is serialized:

- https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/master/packages/functions/src/api/service.ts#L230

The first operation Serializer does (for each property) is:

```js
if (data == null) {
   return null;
}
```

Since `==` is used in lieu of `===`, `undefined` is turned into `null`.

- https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/master/packages/functions/src/serializer.ts#L40